# Not able to get the apt repo update on amazon ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, ping, security-groups

I've one ubuntu instance in EC2 on which i am trying to run sudo apt-get update command and which is giving below error :-

> ```
> Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
>
> Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
>   Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
> 0% [Connecting to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (ip)] [Connecting packet_write_wait: Connection to ip-address port 22:
> ```
>
> Broken pipe

Also i am not able to ping the google as well, i've verified that my security group allows outbound traffic to public

```
All traffic
All
All
0.0.0.0/0
```

I've a another server with same setting ie same VPC, same subnet and security group and its working fine on that server.

Comment: Is your subnet private or public? You can't connect to the Internet from private subnet without configured NAT

Comment: Also you can check Network ACLs within VPC.NACLs are stateless, so you have to configure either outbound and inbound rules to make it work.

Comment: my subnet is public and as i mentioned i've another instance which is in same VPC,subnet and using same security group and its working fine there.

Comment: And does the non-working instance have a public IP address associated with it?

Comment: no it doesn't have.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot , is it possible to assign the public ip to instance once its launched ?

Comment: @AntonMakovetsky , where you check whether my subnet is private or public ?

Comment: A public subnet usually have a default route pointing to the Internet Gateway. Each instance running in that subnet needs an public or Elastic IP address to communicate with the outside world.
And one more - you can not assign public IP to the launched instance. But you can do it with Elastic IP.